# Hide URL download from "internet download manager" eyes?

Tags: php, mysql

On a music site, my users listen to music via a player. Please let me know that how can I hide URL download from "internet download manager" eyes on this site?
My programming languages are PHP + MYSQL.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. What kind of player are you using? What kind of format is the music in? Chances are, though, that there is no way to do what you want, because the music needs to get to the client's machine *somehow*

Comment: It's up to the client's configuration to decide what to do with downloads. There may be some specific HTTP Headers you can use in the general case, but off-hand I don't know what they'd be.

Comment: Seeing as this is already the second question in this direction, maybe you're better off telling us what kind of problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Definitely not possible.  Anything that can be sent to the client can be saved by something.

Comment: @Brad yes, but it can be made *very* hard. Try ripping an archived BBC radio show to see what I mean. I've had to go back to actually play, and run an audio capture program in the background to record stuff from them.

Comment: Any insight as to why this is being closed?  Also, @Pekka it looks like they are using Flash Media Server.  There are handy tools available for ripping this.  I haven't tried this one, but it claims to do it:  http://deceptiveresolution.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/i-can-rip-any-bbc-iplayer-amazon-youtube-etc-streaming-flv/

Comment: @Brad I have a strong tendency to close this as long as it's so badly and hazily worded. I'll vote to reopen if it gets improved. Thanks for the link, I'll try it out! (Although they did some changes to their streaming technology in 2010, since which point it's been impossible for me to rip the stream with any tool, and I tried a number of them. The blog post is from 2008 so it may be out of date, but I'll try anyway.)

Comment: @Pekka;my problem is this that i don't want that user download music illegaly,i know that people can do it if they want to do ,but not clear as can do it with IDM.

Comment: @Pwkka;please let me know that why my question is not a real question?

Answer (score 2):

Laurent's suggestion of temporary URLs is a good one.  Much along those same lines, you can use cookies to validate a path only for a short time, keeping some sort of token to access the music that is only valid for a particular song, and only for a particular amount of time.

Something I have seen on other music sites (and this depends on the player) is splitting up the audio data into chunks.  Each HTTP request gets another chunk, and the player reassembles.  There is overhead with this method though, and it isn't foolproof.

You might also try HTTPS, but not all clients like this.  Make sure to validate where the data is coming from so someone doesn't insert a proxy in the middle.  This is generally bad practice though.

What you are asking for isn't technically possible.  If it can get to the client, it can be reassembled by something.  All you can do is make it difficult with these two methods.  Of course, it wouldn't take much effort for someone to write software to reassemble those chunks.

You could use other methods, such as encrypting the data.  Again though, not 100% foolproof.

Comment: +1 A reasonable answer to a not-actually-that-unreasonable question. It's an interesting exercise at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can only make saving content from your site more difficult - not impossible. You can also make traditional download managers mostly useless. If your computer can play it, however, there will be a way to capture it, even if it involves plugging the speaker output to a separate audio recording device.

A few approaches that you can use either alone or even together:

- Use single-use or time-restricted URLs - this will mostly guard against hot-linking from external sites
- Use session cookies so that download managers without access to the browser cookies cannot be used.
- Use CAPTCHAs to filter out any automated bots.
- Use a custom streaming protocol and associated player.
- Use encryption - and watch your server CPU load.

Whatever you do, you'd better think very carefully about a few things:

- Whether employing such measures will make your site harder to use, inconveniencing your users.
- Whether you will create compatibility issues that will enrage your (potentially paying) users.
- Whether proprietary streaming protocols are worth the development and maintenance cost, in relation to the abuse that you are seeing.

It all depends on the kind of abuse that you are seeing (or suspect that is happening) and the benefit-to-cost ratio of each approach.

Comment: Mmm, very nice points. The CAPTCHA - inconvenient as it is - could make ripping *very* difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, the download manager needs to know the URL to be able to download the file.

What you could do instead is generate a single-use URL using PHP, which would mean the URL displayed would be useless after the first download (or after a given amount of time, might be safer to keep the URL alive for say 5 minutes to avoid failed retries)

Comment: But how han i do it with php ?i want that IDM don't understand the main url of music streaming in player.